# How do I auto-expand a JTree when setting a new TreeModel?

Tags: java, swing, tree, jtree

I have a custom `JTree` and a custom `JModel`; I would for the JTree to "auto-expand" when I give it a new model. At the moment, it simply collapse all the nodes to the root.

Here is an example:

```
private class CustomTree extends JTree {

    @Override
    public boolean isExpanded(TreePath path) {
        return ((Person) path.getLastPathComponent).hasChildren();

}

private class CustomTreeModel extends TreeModel {

    // ... omitting various implementation details

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object object) {
        return !((Person) object).hasChildren();
    }

}

Model model = new Model();
Person bob = new Person();
Person alice = new Person();
bob.addChild(alice);
model.setRoot(bob);
JTree tree = new CustomTree(new CustomTreeModel(model));
```

At this point, the tree correctly displays:

```
- BOB
  - ALICE
```

where Alice is a child of Bob (both in the data and in the visual tree)

However, if I call:

```
tree.setModel(new CustomTreeModel(model));
```

everything is collapsed:

```
+ BOB
```

**Is there a way to "auto-expand" everything in the tree when setting a new model?**

Comment: no ideas from this code and description, all notifiers & listener go away after model is changed,

Comment: @mKorbel I believe my answer below solves my problem.

Comment: :-) ............... do not use index by int, you can lost this index, have to store all accesible about node inc. Object value (my view)

Comment: Expand on setting a new model.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @mKorbel I'm sorry I don't quite understand - I can _lose_ the tree.getRowCount() index? How?

Comment: @AndrewThompson `tree.setModel(new CustomTreeModel(model))`

Comment: models can be different, tree.getRowCount() <> with old model, or <> structure of nodes, or <> value from one, two or all elements, if yes then don't recreate a model use implemented menthods and notifiers, have you issue with nodeChanged, post an SSCCE, where you replace an new model with different structure, then this question make me sence

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Your solution (as posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211697/837530) seemed to work for me only for the top level tree nodes.

But I needed to expand all the a descendants node. So I solved it with the following recursive method:

```
private void expandAllNodes(JTree tree, int startingIndex, int rowCount){
    for(int i=startingIndex;i<rowCount;++i){
        tree.expandRow(i);
    }

    if(tree.getRowCount()!=rowCount){
        expandAllNodes(tree, rowCount, tree.getRowCount());
    }
}
```

which is invoked with

```
expandAllNodes(tree, 0, tree.getRowCount());
```

where, `tree` is a `JTree`.

Unless someone has a better solution.

Comment: see sdasdadas answer below for a 3 line solution without recursion.

Comment: You're saving the rowCount, then expanding that many lines. But by the time you've expanded them, more lines are added. If you change `i<rowCount` in your `for` statement to `i<tree.getRowCount()`, it will keep expanding from the top, and won't end until it has reached all the expanded rows, no need for recursion.

Answer (score 54):

The following worked for me (called after setting the new model):

```
for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
    tree.expandRow(i);
}
```

Comment: @all: this solution is sufficient, here's no need for recursion

Comment: As for "why": it works because `expandRow()` will show more rows, making `getRowCount()` increase after each expansion. Trying to be smart by storing `n = getRowCount()` and `for (i=0; i<n; i++)` will not work.

Answer (score 10):

There's also this non-recursive version.

```
private void expandAllNodes(JTree tree) {
    int j = tree.getRowCount();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < j) {
        tree.expandRow(i);
        i += 1;
        j = tree.getRowCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class JTreeNodeAutoExpandCollapse extends JFrame {
    public JTreeNodeAutoExpandCollapse() throws HeadlessException {
        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode chapter1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Chapter 1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1.1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1.2");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1.3");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub31 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1.3.1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub32 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1.3.2");

        root.add(chapter1);
        chapter1.add(sub1);
        chapter1.add(sub2);
        chapter1.add(sub3);
        sub3.add(sub31);
        sub3.add(sub32);

        final JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        expandTree(tree, false);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JButton expandAll = new JButton("Expand All");
        expandAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                expandTree(tree, true);
            }
        });

        JButton collapseAll = new JButton("Collapse All");
        collapseAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                expandTree(tree, false);
            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(expandAll, BorderLayout.WEST);
        buttonPanel.add(collapseAll, BorderLayout.EAST);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void expandTree(JTree tree, boolean expand) {
        TreeNode root = (TreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
        expandAll(tree, new TreePath(root), expand);
    }

    private void expandAll(JTree tree, TreePath path, boolean expand) {
        TreeNode node = (TreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();

        if (node.getChildCount() >= 0) {
            Enumeration enumeration = node.children();
            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                TreeNode n = (TreeNode) enumeration.nextElement();
                TreePath p = path.pathByAddingChild(n);

                expandAll(tree, p, expand);
            }
        }

        if (expand) {
            tree.expandPath(path);
        } else {
            tree.collapsePath(path);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JTreeNodeAutoExpandCollapse().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void expandTree(){
    int row = 1;
    while (row++ < tree.getRowCount()){
        tree.expandRow(row);
    }

public void collapseTree(){
    int row = tree.getRowCount() - 1;
    while (row-- > 0){
        tree.collapseRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Also, since this is an old question, check that your answer isn't already contained in another answer.

Comment: @Alexander,  in expandTree() method int row = 1; should be start from 0(int row = 0;) else the first node after Root node will not be expand.